# bokeh: customjs callback not interacting with my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, callback, widget, slider, bokeh

I'm trying to create a plot with slider widget using Bokeh

my main issue is that slider widget is not interacting with my python code.
I've tried many other ways posted online, but still couldn't find solution for my problem.

Here is what I want from the code below:
I would like to show different line curves depending on the value of the slider. Initial slider value is set to 32, and I would like to update the plot as slider moves. 
My guess is somehow callback of customjs is not working properly, but I couldn't figure out the exact source of the problem. I've already spent quite a bit of time (more than 6 hours!) but still cannot find appropriate solutions.

```
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_notebook, push_notebook, output_file

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': BER_log[32], 'y': v_axis })
source_ber = ColumnDataSource(data={'BER': BER_log})

update_plot = CustomJS(args=dict(source_data=source, source_ber=source_ber), code="""
var data = source_data.data;
var data_ber = source_ber.data;
var ts = tstamp_slider.value;
data['x'] = data_ber['BER'][ts]
source.change.emit();
source_ber.change.emit();
""")
tstamp_slider = Slider(start=0, end=int(oneUI/Ts), value=32, step=1, title="Time Stamp", callback=update_plot)
update_plot.args["tstamp_slider"] = tstamp_slider

voltber = figure(title='Voltage Margin', y_axis_label='Volts (V)', x_axis_label='BER',
           y_range=[v_scale.min, v_scale.max], x_range=[-50, 0])
r = voltber.line(x=source.data['x'], y=source.data['y'], line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

layout = column(voltber, widgetbox(tstamp_slider))

show(layout)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be02b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I observed for the function you should use {}, did you try to put it? Some thing like:

```
update_plot = CustomJS(args=dict(source_data=source, source_ber=source_ber), code="""
var data = source_data.data;
var data_ber = source_ber.data;
var ts = tstamp_slider.value;
{data['x'] = data_ber['BER'][ts]}
source.change.emit();
source_ber.change.emit();
""")
```

Source: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html 
(it's my first post here, I do not know if this is correct, please let me know :) )